# Itext7 HTML to PDF conversion using Html2pdf when HTML is passed as input string and CSS as file

Tags: itext7

I have already implemented the HTML to PDF conversion via Itext 5 XMLWorker. Please find the code below:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var document = new Document())
{
 using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
 {
  document.Open();
  document.SetMargins(30, 60, 60, 60);
  using (var strReader = new StringReader(htmlToExport))
  {
    //Set factories
    var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    //Set css
    var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver   (false);
    // cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath  ("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"),
    //    true);
    cssResolver.AddCssFile("http://localhost:8902/Content/bootstrap.css", true);
    //Export
    var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
    var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    var xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
    xmlParse.Parse(strReader);
    xmlParse.Flush();
  }
  document.Close();
  }
}
```

I am unable to find the relevant example to full fill above requirement in Itext7.

Comment: I will take care in future apologies

Answer (score 2):

You no longer have to pass/add the CSS file explicitly, pdfHTML(Html2Pdf was the internal development name for a while), can pick up stylesheets linked in the HTML. You might optionally have to define a base resource location if your CSS is not located in the same folder as your HTML.

In your HTML, add the following line in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"/>
```

And the conversion code of you want to add them to a

```
File pdf = new File(pdfDest);
pdf.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PdfWriter writer  = new PdfWriter(pdfDest);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(resourceLoc);

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDoc, converterProperties);
pdfDoc.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! With in my application HTML is coming as input string and I am not saving PDF in Drive Location as it will be downloaded from Browser itself. In that case according to my understanding  do I need to set converterProperties.SetTagWorkerFactory(iText.Html2pdf.Attach.ITagWorkerFactory);
converterProperties.SetCssApplierFactory? how to set converterProperties in above scenario? is there any other alternative ?

Comment: HTMLConvertor#converToPdf() accepts a number of different inputs, including a string and outputstream. You only need to set the TagWorkerFactory and CssApplierfactory if you're using custom tagworkers and css appliers.

Comment: As I am new to Itext 7 Can you please provide example .in .Net  C#  to set TagWorkerFactory CssApplierfactory  object for converterProperties.SetTagWorkerFactory(iText.Html2pdf.Attac‌​h.ITagWorkerFactory)‌​; converterProperties.SetCssApplierFactory.  As The method  parameter  Interface , I am looking how to initialise Interface objects with in Parameter

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples here:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/converting-html-pdf

Comment: With my POC for Itext 7 (HTML to PDF) (Html2pdf), I am facing issues regarding BootStap.css. When I am giving custom css class Itext 7 tool able to render styles mention in the custom CSS file. Itext 7 unable to render CSS styles mention in the bootstrap.css. Please suggest what to do?

Comment: @AmitGera Some styles just are not supported yet. Declarations concerning floating elements like inline-block are still in development. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess the bootstrap css file contains at least some of those.