# BootStrap Classes supported in iText.Html2pdf

Tags: itext7, html2pdf

I am very new to iText7. I am trying to create a pdf from a dynamic html string. So far i have been able to create the pdf using  **HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf()**. But the problem I am facing is most of the bootstrap css classes are not working in the pdf.

From the below thread I got the idea that not all bootstrap css class will work in the iText.

[Itext7 HTML to PDF conversion using Html2pdf when HTML is passed as input string and CSS as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157423/itext7-html-to-pdf-conversion-using-html2pdf-when-html-is-passed-as-input-string)

If anyone can suggest a work around for this or may be share what are the css classes are supported in iText Html2Pdf that will be very helpful. Thanks!!

**HTML snippet:**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 table-bordered hideLeftBorder 
    hideBottomBorder" style="padding-bottom:0.5%">

    <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row table-bordered hideLeftBorder hideRightBorder">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                MY HEADER ONE
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                Adress: xxx, yyy,zzzz
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row table-bordered hideRightBorder hideBottomBorder 
        hideLeftBorder">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                MY HEAD
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Code:**

```
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputDirectoryFile);

            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

            pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

            ConverterProperties cp = new ConverterProperties().SetBaseUri(resourceUri);

            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlstring)),pdfDocument,cp);
            pdfDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap do you use? I don't think that the definitive list of supported bootstrap classes exists, however I can say that Bootstrap v3 should be reasonably well supported, but it's worse for Bootstrap v4. Bootstrap v4 relies on flex layout a lot and it's not supported by pdfHTML as of yet.

Comment: Its is Bootstrap v3.0.0 i am using. Yet classes like row and col are not working in my generated pdf. Is there any example link that you could share? It will be great help. Thank!